# Get remote host IP address and port QUdpSocket

Tags: qt, udp, ip

I use QUdpSocket to create an UDP server. When a client connects to it, I would like to know the client's IP address and port number. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried [looking in the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#readDatagram)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side you can see the address that the data has come from using:

```
readDatagram(char * data, qint64 maxSize, QHostAddress * address = 0, quint16 * port = 0)
```

To read the data when you get a readyRead() signal.

Answer (score 0):

```
QHostAddress sender;
quint16 senderPort;

socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, &senderPort);

QString received = QString(buffer);

qDebug() << "Message received on IP:" << socket->localAddress().toString() << "Port:" << socket->localPort();
qDebug() << "Message from:" << sender.toString();
qDebug() << "Message Port:" << senderPort;
qDebug() << "Message:" << received;
```

This is the correct way to get the senders address.